# Python Crash Course Alien Game - Replace background colour with background .bmp image

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I have a working Alien Invasion game which is from the Python Crash Course book. However, I am applying modifications. I am trying to replace the value of `bg_color` to represent a background image stored in my project folder instead of a colour i.e

```
self.bg_color = pygame.image.load('images/space.bmp')
```

Currently the AlienInvasion class imports the background colour from a class called settings stored in a sep file called settings.py

```
class Settings:
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's static settings."""
        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230,230,230)
```

AlienInvasion is the main game class which sets up the game.

```
class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        """create a settings object using the imported settings class"""
        self.settings = Settings()
        """initialise the game display using the settings saved within the settings file"""
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        """ assign the imported ship attributes to a new ship instance - "Self" in the call references to a call of AlienInvasion as a class """
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        """ run the game in full screen mode """
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
        # Set the background color.
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

Update_screen updates the screen continually as the game progresses and handles the background colour when the game is run

```
def _update_screen(self):
            """Update the images on the screen and flip to the new screen"""  
            # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop. Use the settings file here
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
```

I think my issue is to do with .fill() applying only to colour values (230, 230, 230). But I essentially want the screen to update with the background image rather than a static colour. Can somebody please assist? Is there another function I should be using instead of .fill()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the background in `Settings`:

```py
class Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        # [...]
    
        self.bg_color = pygame.image.load('images/space.bmp')
```

Get the background from the `Settings` object in the constructor of `AlienInvasion`. If the background image is a different size than the display, I recommend using [`pygame.transform.smoothscale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale)  to scale the background to the correct size:

```py
class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""
    def __init__(self):
        # [...]
        self.settings = Settings()
        # [...]

        self.bg_color = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.settings.bg_color, 
                            self.screen.get_size())
```

[`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the background rather rather than [`fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) the display surface:

```py
class AlienInvasion:
    # [...]

    def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.settings.bg_color, (0, 0))
```

`blit` draw one image onto another. In this case it draw the background image (*Surface*) on the *Surface* which is associated to the display.

---

Note, that the name `bg_color` is misleading. If you are using a background image, you should rename it (e.g. `bg_image` or `bg_surface`).

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
self.screen.blit(your_image, (0, 0))
```

instead of:

```
self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

your_image should be the size of screen and tuple is position

Answer (score 0):

Use fill() only when you want to fill backround with some color and blit when want to update screen. fill() is great method but when change color but rather use blit for changing something on screen or updating it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31332883)